# RxJs - get defer() observable value when other emits

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is actually for angular app.

I have a filter form fields which emit values whenever user changes their values (typing, for example). This is the first Observable.

```
this.filterFrm.valueChanges.pipe(...);
```

And I have another Observable which just gives me the current form validity value:

```
const formIdValid = defer(() => of(this.filterFrm.valid));
```

How can I combine these two so when form values change I always get the current `form.valid` value?

Here's what I tried:

```
    this.filterFrm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        concatMap((frmValue) => formIdValid.pipe(map((isValid) => ({ isValid, frmValue })))),
        filter(({ isValid, frmValue }) => isValid),
        takeUntil(this.destroy)
      )
      .subscribe((filterCriteria) => this.filterChanged.emit(filterCriteria));
```

But it only emits single value for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant really think of any situations in which you'd want an observable like this:

`const formIdValid = defer(() => of(this.filterFrm.valid));`

It's basically just using a bit of extra computing power to read `this.filterFrm.valid` wherever you subscribe.

For example, your solution can be re-written like this without any issue:

```js
this.filterFrm.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(frmValue => ({
    frmValue, 
    isValid: this.filterFrm.valid,
  })),
  tap(console.dir),
  filter(({ isValid }) => isValid),
  map(({ frmValue }) => ({
    searchPhrase: frmValue.filterFld,
    startDate: frmValue.startDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.startDateFld) : undefined,
    endDate: frmValue.endDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.endDateFld) : undefined
  })),
  takeUntil(this.destroy)
).subscribe(
  filterCriteria => this.filterChanged.emit(filterCriteria)
);
```

Or if you don't care about your `console.dir` logging isValid, then this is also the same:

```js
this.filterFrm.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap(console.dir),
  filter(_ => this.filterFrm.valid),
  map(frmValue => ({
    searchPhrase: frmValue.filterFld,
    startDate: frmValue.startDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.startDateFld) : undefined,
    endDate: frmValue.endDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.endDateFld) : undefined
  })),
  takeUntil(this.destroy)
).subscribe(
  filterCriteria => this.filterChanged.emit(filterCriteria)
);
```

#### Aside: What is defer really doing?

consider the following:

```js
let num = 10;

const $1 = of(num);
const $2 = defer(()=>of(num));
const $3 = of(1).pipe(map(_ => num));
const $4 = of(1).pipe(mapTo(num));

num++;

$1.subscribe(console.log);
$2.subscribe(console.log);
$3.subscribe(console.log);
$4.subscribe(console.log);
```

If you run this, what do you expect as output? What you need to understand to answer this properly is when the value of `num` is resolved. For both, `$1` and `$4`, this is done when the observable is created, which means that you get the first value of `num`. For `$2` and `$3`, `num` is resolved when the lambda given to `defer`/`map` is invoked.

- `defer` doesn't invoke its factory function until subscription.
- `map` invokes its transformation function each time a new value arrives, which is some time after subscription at the earliest.

Therefore, both `defer` and `map` end up accessing the second value of `num`

**The Output**

```
10
11
11
10
```

---

#### Back to `this.filterFrm.valid`

The problem comes from when this.filterFrm.valid is resolved. A function (in this case the lambda given to `filter`) doesn't access that variable until it is invoked. Filter only invokes the function when it gets a new value and so for every new value, the filter will access `this.filterFrm.valid` anew.

So in this case, you're not gaining anything with `defer`

Comment: hm... the reason I used `defer()` was the solution similar to yours didn't work. But I will try it again tomorrow because it's really interesting.

Comment: @alvipeo I added in a short blurb to describe when/how this should work.

Comment: ok, I tried and you're correct. it does work with just a `filter()`. but I did try this... it was probably something else that made it fail. the page is pretty complex though.

Answer (score 2):

Right after I posted the question, I made it work!

```
    this.filterFrm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        concatMap((frmValue) => formIdValid.pipe(map((isValid) => ({ isValid, frmValue })))),
        tap(console.dir),
        filter(({ isValid, frmValue }) => isValid),
        map(({ isValid, frmValue }) => ({
          searchPhrase: frmValue.filterFld,
          startDate: frmValue.startDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.startDateFld) : undefined,
          endDate: frmValue.endDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.endDateFld) : undefined
        })),
        takeUntil(this.destroy)
      )
      .subscribe((filterCriteria) => this.filterChanged.emit(filterCriteria));
```

## UPDATE

Yes, in this particular case `defer()` is not required. But it was a nice learning experiment anyway.

```
    this.filterFrm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        filter(() => this.filterFrm.valid),
        map((frmValue) => ({
          searchPhrase: frmValue.filterFld,
          startDate: frmValue.startDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.startDateFld) : undefined,
          endDate: frmValue.endDateFld ? new Date(frmValue.endDateFld) : undefined
        })),
        takeUntil(this.destroy)
      )
      .subscribe((filterCriteria) => this.filterChanged.emit(filterCriteria));
```

Comment: When destructuring, you don't need to assign all of an object's properties. `filter(({ isValid }) => isValid)` and `map(({ frmValue }) => ({...` is a bit more clear.

Comment: Well, all my projects use --strict (tsconfig.json) so that's a habit to have a very explicit code.